# How to display drupal custom form if user clicks adwords advertisments?

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, google-ads-api

My client want to published some adwords advertisement on Google. The website only purpose is presenting info about it's company and it's not an e-commerce site. Since adwords final result depend on conversion we decided to add simple form including following fields.

1) Name:

2) Email Address:

3) Occupation:

However, we need to display this form if only a person clicks on the 10% discount adword advertisement via Search or Display network. We think by user submitting this form user may contact us is definite.

My Questions are:

1) Is there a way to display this discount form only if user click the Google add? if so could you pls clarify

2) Is there a module for Drupal 7 to create custom form fields?

3) Otherwise is there a different method to achieve what I explained above?

Answer (score 1):

1. The [Referer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.36) HTTP header field might tell you the URL of the page from which the user might have come to your site.

The first *might* means, there is no quarantee that it is present.
The second *might* means, if it is present, there is no quarantee that it is accurate.

2. The Fields module can be used to create custom form fields. It is part of the Drupal 7 core. It can be used to attach fields to *bundles*. A bundle is a set of *entities*. EXamples are

- The nodes of a node type are a bundle
- All users are a bundle
- The terms of a vocabulary are a bundle

The Fields module provides an API to define new entity types and groups them into bundles.

Answer (score 1):

1 - You can create a unique [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) and exclude it from search engines in your robots.txt file. This will allow it to be accessed directly via the URL, but it won't be picked up by any search engine, and therefor can't be found by anonymous users. You'll have to add it in the robots file as such:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /your-page-path/

You may also have to exclude it from your site's search (if you have it).

2 - If you haven't already tried the [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) module, it's a great module for creating custom forms and gathering submissions right within the Drupal site.

Comment: This is great but can you please tell me a way to make sure that URL shouldn't exist without ad-sense ads. At least can you tell me to a display a custom error message if user visit that page via directly or via any other way?

Comment: As Oswald mentioned below, you may be able to check the HTTP referrer info and only display the form if the user is coming from one of your google ads. The data you'd need would likely be in $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. You could print that out on your form to see what the value is when you come to that form from your ad. Then, add a check using hook_form_alter to only display the form if the HTTP REFERRER contains a certain string/url. Not sure how familiar you are with all that, but the hook_form_alter will usually go in a custom module for your site.

Comment: And as Oswald also mentioned, the HTTP_REFERER is not guaranteed to be there, or be accurate. But you can at least give it a shot. Otherwise if you just exclude if in your robots.txt file and make sure it's excluded from your site search and index, there's no way people would be able to find it unless someone physically gave them a link to it.